# Replacing unknown characters up to new line

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a String with a list of different values, something like this:

```
Joe = 544
Sam = 43
Jenny = 126
```

I have to either replace Sam and his value with a new value or completely delete the line up to the new line so I can rewrite his value again. I would prefer replacing.

I have found some good resources on how to do both loosely, but I don't know how to exactly apply it to my problem.

I don't know the boundaries of Regex, but I imagine its possible to do this without using a Split? I don't have much experience with Regex at all and the syntax is really confusing to me.

I was thinking in pseudocode something like:

```
String.replaceAll("Sam = ?*\n", "Sam = 83\n");
```

Comment: For regex, you'll need to use replaceAll(), not just replace().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just do this:

```
String names = "Joe = 544\nSam = 43\nJenny = 126";
names = names.replaceAll("(?<=^|\\n)Sam = \\d+", "Sam = 83");
```

### Demo

This replaces `Sam =` followed by some number, when what precedes `Sam` is either a newline *or* the start of string (for the case where maybe Sam happens to appear first).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks like this will work. I'm definitely going to keep this, I can think of a lot of projects that might need me to do this again.

Comment: @Allan I was going to ask, but I hate groveling for points, and ideally we should not have to.  But, leaving many good question with answers dangling also doesn't help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This will add a new value for Sam.

```
text.replaceAll("Sam = .*\n", "Sam = 123\n");
```

Regex explanation: .* matches any characters that appear after 'Sam = ' and includes them in the match, and then replaces the whole String that starts with 'Sam = ...'.

Comment: This won't work, at least not in its current form ([see here](http://rextester.com/SDZS30316)).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This definitely helped me too. I actually needed it to do strings and not just numbers, but with your help also I was able to change to do so from Tim's answer by doing .*+   , Tim is right though in its current form it doesn't work. This is what worked for me: names = names.replaceAll("(?<=^|\\n)Sam = .*+", "Sam = 83");

Comment: Nice catch @TimBiegeleisen - I fixed the typo.